# Magento2: how to get the SKUs from the serialized condition in cart price rules

Tags: magento2

I need to get the SKUs from cart price rule to assign a specific attribute to them, but the condition is saved in the database serialized, and I want to make foreach loop to extract all the SKU's from the serialized condition :

```
?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objrules = $obj->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory')->create();
$rules = $objrules->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("is_active", "1");

 foreach ($rules as $rule) {
     echo $rule->getConditionsSerialized() . "\n";

     }
```

and the result of the serialized condition is:

```
{"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":1,"is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all","conditions":[{"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Subselect","attribute":"qty","operator":">=","value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"any","conditions":[{"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"sku","operator":"==","value":"100817069","is_value_processed":false,"attribute_scope":null},{"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"sku","operator":"==","value":"100817051","is_value_processed":false,"attribute_scope":null},{"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"sku","operator":"==","value":"100817561","is_value_processed":false,"attribute_scope":null},{"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"sku","operator":"==","value":"100817579","is_value_processed":false,"attribute_scope":null}]}]}
```

so, how can we extract all the SKU's from this condition.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objrules = $obj->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory')->create();
$rules = $objrules->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("is_active", "1");
$skus = [];

if ($rules) {
    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        $ruleData = $rule->getConditionsSerialized();
        if ($ruleData) {
            $ruleDataArray = json_decode($ruleData, true);
            if (isset($ruleDataArray['conditions'])) {
                $conditions = $ruleDataArray['conditions'];
                foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
                    if (isset($condition['conditions'])) {
                        $productConditions = $condition['conditions'];
                        foreach ($productConditions as $productCondition) {
                            if (isset($productCondition['value'])) {
                                $skuValues = $productCondition['value'];
                                $skuValues = explode(",",$skuValues);
                                foreach ($skuValues as $skuValue) {
                                    $skus[] = $skuValue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$uniqSkus = array_unique($skus);
print_r($uniqSkus);
exit;
```